# Magento 2.3: My layout handle is not working in email template

Tags: magento2.3, layout, cart, email-templates, transactional-mail

I had created the custom email template in that I declared the layout handle email template it is not working what can I do for it. I passed the data from the controller but the email is not coming with the data.

I create basic module **VendorName/ModuleName** inside that registration.php,module.xml,route.xml etc.

**Custom Email Template**

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\etc\email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="VendorName_RequestForQuote_quote_email_template" label="Quote Request" file="quote" type="html" module="VendorName_RequestForQuote" area="frontend"/>

</config>
```

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\view\frontend\email\quote.html**

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- pathe of template header-->

<table>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1 style="text-align:center">{{trans 'Request For Quote Mail'}}</h1>
            <h3>{{trans 'Requested Items'}}</h3>
            <p>{{trans 'Customer Name : <span class="no-link">%customer_names</span>' customer_names=$myvar1 |raw}}</p>
            <p>{{trans 'Customer Mail : <span class="no-link">%customer_email</span>' customer_email=$myvar2 |raw}}</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{layout handle="quote_quote_items" items=$items area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!--footer of template-->
```

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\RequestForQuote\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Contact\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */

    protected $resultPageFactory;
     /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;
    /*** @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context*/


     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $contactsConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         try {
            $this->sendEmail();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('contact_us');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('contact_us', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        return $resultPage;
    }
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

        $variablevalue1 = "Test";
        $variablevalue2 = "test@example.com";

        /* Here we prepare data for our email  */
        /* Receiver Detail  */
        $receiverInfo = [
            'name' => 'Reciver Name',
            'email' => 'reciver@email.com'
        ];


        /* Sender Detail  */
        $senderInfo = [
            'name' => 'Quote Requests',
            'email' => 'sender@email.com',
        ];



        /* Assign values for your template variables  */
        $emailTemplateVariables = array();
        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $variablevalue1;
        $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $variablevalue2;
        $emailTempVariables['items'] = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();;


        /* We write send mail function in helper because if we want to 
           use same in other action then we can call it directly from helper */  

        /* call send mail method from helper or where you define it*/  
        $this->_objectManager->get('VendorName\RequestForQuote\Helper\Email')->yourCustomMailSendMethod(
              $emailTempVariables,
              $senderInfo,
              $receiverInfo
          );
    }
}
```

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\Helper\Email.php**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\RequestForQuote\Helper;

/**
 * Custom Module Email helper
 */
class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD  = '';
    /* Here section and group refer to name of section and group where you create this field in configuration*/

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
    */
    protected $temp_id;

    /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    * @param Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder; 
    }

    /**
     * Return store configuration value of your template field that which id you set for template
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getConfigValue($path, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return store 
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    /**
     * Return template id according to store
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTemplateId($xmlPath)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue($xmlPath, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
    }

    /**
     * [generateTemplate description]  with template file and tempaltes variables values                
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $template =  $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('VendorName_RequestForQuote_quote_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                                 store of template for which you prepare it */
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
        return $this;        
    }

    /**
     * [sendInvoicedOrderEmail description]                  
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    /* your send mail method*/
    public function yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId('VendorName_RequestForQuote_quote_email_template');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();    
        $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);    
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();        
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }

}
```

**app\design\frontend\VendorName\ChildTheme\VendorName_RequestForQuote\layout\quote_quote_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="Quote Page" template="VendorName_RequestForQuote::quoteItems.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app\design\frontend\VendorName\market_child\VendorName_RequestForQuote\templates\quoteItems.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_items = $block->getItems();
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $om->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $thumbNail =  $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';
    $productRepository = $storeManager = $om->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
    $totalAmount = 0;
?>
<div class="block block-dashboard-orders">
    <div class="block-title order"><strong>Quote Products</strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="table-wrapper orders-recent">
            <table class="data table table-order-items history">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class=" col ">Sl.no</th>
                        <th class=" col ">Product Name</th>
                        <th class=" col ">Quantity</th>
                        <th class=" col ">Product Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                    $counter = 0;
                    <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                        <?php $_product = $productRepository->getById($_item->getProductId()); ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php $product_image_url =  $thumbNail . $_product->getThumbnail();?>
                                <img id='image' src="<?php echo $product_image_url; ?>" style='border-width:0px;height:80px;width:80px;'>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); ?>">
                                    <p class="product-name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
                                </a>
                                <p class="sku">
                                    <b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo  __('SKU') . ' : '  ?></b>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl() . $_item->getProduct()->getUrlKey(); ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                                <p class="sku">
                                    <b><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo  __('Available Store') . ' : '  ?></b>
                                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_product->getAvailableStore()); ?>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="item-qty">
                                <span><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="item-price">
                                <span><?php echo $_item->getOriginalPrice() ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="item-price">
                                <span><?php echo $_item->getQtyOrdered() * $_item->getOriginalPrice() ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <?php
                            $tAmount = $_item->getQtyOrdered() * $_item->getOriginalPrice();
                            $totalAmount += $tAmount;
                            ?>
                        </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: please show your system.xml file code also for more information

Comment: @Msquare i didn't include any system.xml file

Comment: I used system.xml for email sending, if you used then i will help you

Comment: @Msquare i don't know about system.xml can you explain or educate about it

Comment: i add link for understanding system.xml and add code to send email please check and inform me it' helps you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**learn about system.xml click here** [link-1](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html) and [Link-2](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2/)

I follow Magento Default way to send email.

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\etc\adminhtml**

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="requestforquote" translate="label" sortOrder="201">
            <label>Request For Quote</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="quoterequest" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Request For Quote System</label>
            <tab>requestforquote</tab>
            <resource>VendorName_RequestForQuote::quoterequest_config</resource>
            <!-- for Email Configuration -->
            <group id="email_setting"
                   translate="label"
                   type="text"
                   sortOrder="20"
                   showInDefault="1"
                   showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Email Configuration</label>
                <field id="quest_email"
                       translate="label"
                       type="select"
                       sortOrder="50"
                       showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Select Request For Quote Template</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

now create **email_templates.xml**

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\etc**

**email_templates.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="quoterequest_email_setting_quest_email" label="Request For Quote" file="quote.html" type="html" module="VendorName_RequestForQuote" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> here template id is define must be like this **sectionID_groupID_fieldID** which read from **system.xml**

now we create **quote.html** which define in **email_templates.xml**

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\view\frontend\email**

**quote.html**

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} 

<h1> Email come add your content </h1>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**app\code\VendorName\RequestForQuote\Helper**

**Email.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\RequestForQuote\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Email extends AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD = 'quoterequest/email_setting/quest_email';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function setStoreScope()
    {
        return ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
    }

    public function getEmailTemplteName()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD, $this->setStoreScope());
    }

    public function sendEmail($emailTemplateVariables, $senderInfo, $receiverInfo)
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->getEmailTemplteName())
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'], $receiverInfo['name']);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage()(__('Email send fail'));
        }
    }
}
```

> here you have to must pass value like this

**$emailTemplateVariables** must be array

**$senderInfo = "sender email"**

**$receiverInfo** must be array

```
$receiverInfo = [];

$receiverInfo['email'] = "receiver email";

$receiverInfo['name'] = "receiver name";
```

> now you can call any where **sendEmail()** method to send email.

***I Hope This Helps You.***