# How to create a custom email template and show it in store configuration dropdown?

Tags: magento2, configuration, email-templates

I want to provide another option for email template without creating the etc/config.xml or etc/system.xml, because i just need to add the new email option to the dropdown without creating new input field in store configuration. I tried it like this, but no luck:

**etc/email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="test_email_template" label="Test" file="test.html" type="html" module="Test_Test" area="frontend"/> 
</config>
```

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307810/82670

Comment: In which dropdown you want to show more options?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya in store configuration email templates dropdown, for example store > configuration >  sales > sales emails

Comment: You need to add totally your custom or you want modify old?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya modify the old ones

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the old template then you need to do this things :

```
 1. Go To Admin.
 
 2. Marketing Menu -> Email Templates.

 3. Click on "Add New Template"

 4. Now select which you want to modify and load that template and save it.

 5. Now go to the configuration and you will find that newly created template into your dropdown.
```